# WinRT Accessing same file twice giving Catastrophic failure error

Tags: c#, windows-8, stream, windows-runtime, outputstream

I have created method to save InkManager in local Storage the code is as below. But When I am accessing it twice its me error...

> Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF
>   (E_UNEXPECTED))

What could be the possible error?

The code:

```
try
{
    StorageFile myMerge = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("sign.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);         

    using (IOutputStream signature = await myMerge.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        if (signature != null)
        {
            await _inkManager.SaveAsync(signature);

            signature.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return myMerge;
}
```

Comment: WTF.... "Catastrophic failure"... It's the best error message ever. EPIC

Comment: Yes this is what I am getting as error message

Comment: I know... we had a VB6 application which used to throw  the same error. It's just hilarious.

Comment: Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: Try commenting line `signature.Dispose();`. You won't need `Dispose();` as `using` do that work.

Comment: But the error is coming when this method is called for the second time at  StorageFile myMerge = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("sign.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); line

Comment: Xyroid its not solving the issue

Comment: if the signature variable can really be null, then could the using block be calling Dispose on a null object? I'm not sure, and I figure that would through a NRE, but it might be worth trying getting rid of the using.

Comment: Are you running this in two tasks running simultaneously?

Comment: Have you find a solution? I am having the same problem!